# How to create a usage plan for AWS HTTP API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions, aws-http-api

I am using AWS API Gateway with HTTP API which invokes a lambda function. However HTTP API doesn't include USAGE feature. According to my requirement I need to create a usage for a client depending on the status code of the response sent back by the lambda. Since I cant access the response sent by lambda in API Gateway, I am looking for an custom solution. I am planing to use STEP function.

For example:

Instead of API Gateway directly invoking a lambda function it can call a STEP function where I can execute LambdaA. next it would trigger LambdaB with response from LambdaA as input to LambdaB in a sequential manner. I don't know If this is the right approach

I would like to know what is best way of solving this problem...thanks in advance

Comment: The best way would be to actually use REST API, not HTTP api. Any reason why you can't do this?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Right now it’s Management decision.  Do feel step functions would help me solve this issue @marcin